# Apache poi edate formula not implemented?

Tags: coldfusion, excel-formula, apache-poi, coldfusion-10

I'm trying to implement a couple of formulas when generating a spreadsheet. I've gotten a simple SUM() formula implemented. Now I'm trying to implement one that uses EDATE(). This is the formula as it appears in the original spreadsheet:

=EDATE($AQ$1,-(AC4))

```
// this formula works - summing the previous two cells in each row
var formula = "SUM(AA4:AB4)";

sheet.getRow(3).getCell(28).setCellFormula( formula );

// problem formula
// cell AQ1 is populated by Oracle date
// cell AC4 is populated by a float from the previous formula
formula = "EDATE($AQ$1,-(AC4))";
// throws "Not implemented yet" error
sheet.getRow(3).getCell(29).setCellFormula( formula );
```

According to poi documentation, EDATE is supposed to be implemented. I tried to get the supported function names to see if the implementation that I have doesn't implement it, but got a "Class not found: org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.FunctionEval" error on the first line below:

```
var fe = createObject("java","org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.FunctionEval");
var fs = fe.getSupportedFunctionNames();
var fu = fe.getNotSupportedFunctionNames();
```

I'm not very knowledgeable in Excel to begin with; any chance I'm declaring the formula incorrectly?

**EDIT:**

Per Leigh's hint below, I decided to experiment with using other Excel formulas to accomplish what EDATE is doing. At first, I didn't think it would be possible to create a date using an invalid month ( < 1 or > 12 )... but lo and behold, the DATE function does accept invalid months. So, this is what I came up with:

```
=DATE(YEAR($AQ$1),SUM(MONTH($AQ$1),-INT(AC4)),DAY($AQ$1))
```

Hopefully this'll allow me to put off worrying about updating POI or waiting for CF11 to finally be approved.

Comment: That class should be present in all recent copies of Apache POI - are you possibly using a really old version? And if so, what happens when you upgrade?

Comment: @Gagravarr - They are indeed using an older version (3.6-beta1) that is bundled with CF10. Upgrading would definitely resolve the error. From the comments below it sounds like that is currently waiting on management approval.

Answer (score 3):

> According to poi documentation, EDATE is supposed to be implemented

It is, but it was implemented in a newer version of POI. Since it sounds like you are using the original POI jar bundled with CF10, you are limited by whatever features are supported in that much older version, which unfortunately does not include `EDATE`. You will need to use a newer version of POI. FWIW, that function does work under CF11, which ships with POI 3.9 (see example). So you will need at least POI 3.9 (preferably newer).

For CF10+, the simplest option is to download a newer version of POI and load it dynamically in your Application.cfc via the new setting [this.javaSettings](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/10.0/Developing/WSe61e35da8d318518-106e125d1353e804331-7ffe.html).  It is basically a rip of [Mark Mandel's JavaLoader.cfc](http://www.compoundtheory.com/). Just specify the paths of the individual jars you wish to load, or whole directories to check for jars, ie

```
      // Note - Application must be restarted to apply the settings
      THIS.javaSettings = {LoadPaths = [".\folderWithPOIJars\"] };
```

**[Runnable EDATE Example (CF11+)](http://trycf.com/gist/7c1d815b3d134a5be5a0ee505918e2ff/acf11?theme=monokai)**

```
<cfscript>
    workBook = CreateObject( "java", "org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook").Init();
    sheet = WorkBook.CreateSheet( JavaCast( "string", "my sheetname" ) );

    // For simplicity using cells A1 - A5
    // Simulate rows used in AC4 formula
    sheet.createRow(0).createCell(0).setCellValue( javacast("float", 5) );
    sheet.createRow(1).createCell(0).setCellValue( javacast("float", 7) );

    // Simulate AC4 formula
    sheet.createRow(2).createCell(0).setCellFormula( "SUM(A1:A2)" );
    // Simulate cell populated by Oracle date
    sheet.createRow(3).createCell(0).setCellValue( now() );

    // Finally, apply EDATE formula
    sheet.createRow(4).createCell(0).setCellFormula( "EDATE($A$4,-(A3))" );

    // Using binary stream because trycf.com does not support files for security reasons
    baos = createObject("java", "java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream").init();
    workBook.write( baos );
    baos.close();
</cfscript>

<!--- CF10 lacks support for script version of cfcontent --->
<cfheader name="Content-Disposition" value="inline; filename=test.xlsx">  
<cfcontent type="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"
    variable="#baos.toByteArray()#">
```

Comment: OK, will give it a try. Unfortunately, we need to jump through hoops to get new/updated software installed here.

Comment: I know how that goes. Unfortunately if you want to use that function, dynamically loading a newer version is probably the best option. Other than that, did you look into whether it is possible to replicate the EDATE result with different Excel formula(s)?

Comment: I took your comment as a hint. See my updated question ;-)

Comment: Nice work. You should post it as an official "answer", so it is more visible. Also, that way folks can vote on it as well as the question :-)